# Both headphone and front speaker jack use one single output channel in ALSA

Tags: 16.04, sound, alsa, soundcard

I use both the headphone jack and front speaker jack in my sound card, an ASUS STRIX SOAR. That works fine in Windows, especially with the STRIX drivers, as I can change the output device manually or it plays sound through both outputs. But in Ubuntu I have the following problem:

ALSA handles both output jacks as one channel, named 'PCM Front'. When both headphone and front speaker jack on the sound card are plugged in, Ubuntu only plays sound through the headphones, and plays through Front speakers only when I plug out the headphones.

My sound card has following output jacks: 'Headphone', 'Front', 'Rear', 'Center', 'Side/SPDIF Out'

Alsamixer shows following output channels: 'PCM Front', 'PCM Rear', 'PCM Center', 'PCM Woofer', 'PCM Side'

The speakers are 2.1 stereo speakers with a subwoofer, which have to be plugged to the front speaker jack, which works fine in Windows as mentioned above.

So, in Alsamixer there is no separate headphone channel, as it uses 'PCM Front' for both headphone and front speaker jack. My goal is not to run both devices at the same time (which would be a first step though), but rather to have the ability to have two separate channels in Alsa to mute one or the other device.

Does anyone have a solution for that? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What sound card ?

Comment: ASUS STRIX SOAR 7.1.

Comment: Well if neither pulse audio or alsa will do what you want you will have to try jack

Comment: I'm kind of new to Ubuntu and Linux in general. What is the difference between pulseaudio and alsa? and what is 'jack'? thank you.

Comment: https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/ and http://www.jackaudio.org/ . Try `pavucontrol` - https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/pavucontrol/

Comment: pavucontrol didn't solve my problem,  but it seems to be very useful in general, thanks for that. JACK seems not to work and shows an error, could it be that I have to turn off pulseaudio or alsa first? thank you.

Comment: I understand now that Alsa is more of a kernel, and pulseaudio more of a program that uses alsa to play sound. so should I first turn off pulseaudio to see if it does anything good for me?

Comment: I do not know with that card. Jack is difficult to configure but more versatile then PA or ALSA. If you can not get it working you probably need to file a bug report against the alsa kernel driver.